# How to reset io.elementary.music library in Juno

Tags: music

I wish to remove everything from the music app to start fresh.

I couldn’t find a way other than deleting each song individually but my library is rather large so that’s not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Terminal do `rm .local/share/noise/database_0_3_2.db`
That will delete the database where Noise keeps the library info